# Создание текстовых блоков которые при добавлении нового опускаются на 1 позицию вниз

Tags: c#

Идея такая: хочу создать кнопку, чтобы при нажатии помещал в нужную область textbox.(Эта часть легкая) Но как сделать, чтобы при последующих нажатиях на кнопку, первый текстбокс опускался на позицию вниз и его место заняло второе и так бесконечно??? Ну и еще при удалении все нижнии блоки поднимались, смещались, наверх(но это второй вопрос). Кто поможет идеями?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю самый простой вариант с выставлением `Dock = DockStyle.Top` + `Margin` у `TextBox`-ов и добавлением их в `FlowLayoutPanel`.

Пример: http://rghost.ru/42600921

Comment: А можно думаю и изменить расположение текстбокса при добавлении. Ну чтобы при добавлении он сместился на 20-30 пикселей вниз. Просто думаю надо будет узнать какое это свойство у текстбоксов. Как свойство margin-top в html. Надеюсь есть у них такое свойство

Comment: я обновил ответ, нужно использовать FlowLayoutPanel, иначе нельзя выставить отступы. посмотрите пример.

Answer (score 1):

В WPF можно поместить на форму StackPanel и помещать текстбоксы уже туда, поведение будет очень похожее на описываемое ТС